# how to solve non-linear inequalities with python like 12<x*y<14 and 2x + 3y>40?

Tags: python, math, inequality

I want to solve a system of nonlinear inequality equations, Simplify as follows：
12<x*y<14 and 2*x + 3*y>40, is there any way to find the minimum of x using python,
i konw how to solve linear inequality quations with scipy.optimize.linprog,but i can't find the way to solve non-linear inequality quations,thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765794/python-constrained-non-linear-optimization

Comment: This particular system could be solved using only linear solvers: first consider that y is a parameter, and minimize x. This gives you a formula with the minimum x for each y. Then minimize this formula for y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Z3](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) is a SAT/SMT solver that could be interesting for this type of problems.

Here is an example looking for integer solutions. Note that the given equations are unbounded for floats.

```py
from z3 import Optimize, Int, And

opt = Optimize()
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
opt.add(And(x * y > 12, x * y < 14))
opt.add(2 * x + 3 * y > 40)
opt.minimie(x)
print(opt.check())  # prints sat
print(opt.model())  # prints [y = 13, x = 1]
```